# MoveTowards giving two different results for same input - Unity

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I have prefab and its hierarchy is as follows:

bird

-Outline

--mask

--filler

Now I am using this in `Update` to move the filler:

```
filler.gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
            filler.gameObject.transform.position,
            new Vector3(feedBar.gameObject.transform.position.x, -1.1f, filler.gameObject.transform.position.z),
            (1f / PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("timetofeedbird", 5)) * Time.deltaTime);
```

All the instantiated birds have movement in correct direction. But the last one has a movement in reverse direction.

Here is the GIF to explain the issue:

[image]

Any idea what the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this issue. I don't quite understand it but what did the trick for me was I changed the value of `maxDistanceDelta` to negative. And now its working as expected.

`filler.gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
            filler.gameObject.transform.position,
            new Vector3(feedBar.gameObject.transform.position.x, -1.1f, 
            filler.gameObject.transform.position.z),
            -(1f / PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("timetofeedbird", 5)) * Time.deltaTime);`